# Incompatible event loop type with native transport enabled on linux

Tags: java, vert.x

We are seeing high CPU Usage in vertx with eventloop jstack stuck on  "at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait". So we were trying to use native transport
on linux using "setPreferNativeTransport()" but we are getting following error.

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: incompatible event loop type: 
      io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register(AbstractChannel.java:469)
at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop.register(SingleThreadEventLoop.java:80)
at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop.register(SingleThreadEventLoop.java:74)
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:331)
at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:163)
at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:145)
at com.github.mauricio.async.db.mysql.codec.MySQLConnectionHandler.connect(MySQLConnectionHandler.scala:87)
at com.github.mauricio.async.db.mysql.MySQLConnection.connect(MySQLConnection.scala:84)
at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.pool.AsyncConnectionPool.createConnection(AsyncConnectionPool.java:63)
at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.pool.AsyncConnectionPool.createOrWaitForAvailableConnection(AsyncConnectionPool.java:84)
at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.pool.AsyncConnectionPool.take(AsyncConnectionPool.java:93)
at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.BaseSQLClient.getConnection(BaseSQLClient.java:68)
at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLClientImpl.getConnection(AsyncSQLClientImpl.java:54)
at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.ClientWrapper.getConnection(ClientWrapper.java:52)
at io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLClient.queryWithParams(SQLClient.java:109)
at io.vertx.reactivex.ext.sql.SQLClient.queryWithParams(SQLClient.java:218)
at io.vertx.reactivex.ext.sql.SQLClient.lambda$rxQueryWithParams$6(SQLClient.java:231)
at io.vertx.reactivex.core.impl.AsyncResultSingle.subscribeActual(AsyncResultSingle.java:42)
```

We are using vertx-mysql-postgresql-client and it seems to not support native transport. Has anyone seen this problem ?

We are using 
Vertx: 3.5.3
vertx-mysql-postgresql-client: 3.5.3

Comment: Can you report this to the vertx-mysql-postgresql-client repo on GitHub?

Comment: @tsegismont done https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mysql-postgresql-client/issues/135